# unable to load credentials from aws.properties

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using aws ses in java and getting this error. I have searched on google but getting any answer of my problem. Thats'y i am putting my question here.I have tried many times and have done all changes which i got from google but nothing helped me. Here is my Exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at com.artle.Application.createAwsCredentials(Application.java:48)
at com.artle.Application.createSimpleEmailService(Application.java:65)
at com.artle.Application.sendTestEmail(Application.java:70)
at com.artle.Application.main(Application.java:78)
```

Hre is my **Application.java** file

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean SimpleCORSFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new SimpleCORSFilter());
    //registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
} 

private AWSCredentials createAwsCredentials() throws IOException{

    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            "aws.properties"));
AWSCredentials credentials =new BasicAWSCredentials(
        properties.getProperty("aws.accessKey"),
        properties.getProperty("aws.secretKey"));   

AWSCredentials credentials2=new PropertiesCredentials(
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "aws.properties"));



    return credentials;
}

private AmazonSimpleEmailService createSimpleEmailService() throws IOException{

    return new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(createAwsCredentials());

}

private void sendTestEmail() throws IOException{
 PostMan postMan= new AwsPostMan(createSimpleEmailService());   
 postMan.withFrom("ansh@artle.in").withTo("amit0133@gmail.com").
 withSubject("Email from aws!!").
 withBody("This is a test email from AWS").send();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

new Application().sendTestEmail();

SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 

}

}
```

Line no. 48 is

```
properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            "aws.properties"));
```

I just started to work on amazon web services so please help me.

Comment: BTW: EnableAutoConfiguration, ComponentScan and Configuration annotations are all redundant as SpringBootApplication implies that

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what exactly is going on with your properties file. There are sometimes a bit of a difference between running it in your IDE and how it is actually deployed when doing things like that.

But I think what you likely want to do is to use the Spring Boot application.properties file instead and just get it injected by Spring with @Value annotations

But maybe what you REALLY want to do is to look at [Spring Cloud AWS](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sending_simple_mails) that sets up that stuff for you?

Comment: i dont know how credentials will be load .

Comment: actually i want to run aws ses in my spring boot project to send emails

Comment: Spring Cloud AWS uses the two keys aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey  for credentials. They will be loaded though the usual Spring properties providers. For Spring Boot see the page on that: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html